# Civilization IV: How to play multiplayer with Mac and Windows?

Tags: technical-issues, civilization-4

How can I set up a multiplayer game of Civ IV with one Mac OSX player and one Windows player? Both players are running Civ through Steam. The Windows player is running Windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

When you install through Steam it appears that the default Mac OSX version of Civ IV and the Windows version of Civ IV are different.

This is the fastest way I have found of setting up a game:

1. On the Windows machine, find 'Civ IV' in Steam and right-click
2. Click on the `Betas` tab
3. Under 'Select the beta you would like to opt in to', click on the drop-down menu and select `Original Release – UNSUPPORTED`
4. Let Civ update, and launch when finished
5. Now when you launch the game, both players should have the `Multiplayer` -> `Direct IP Connection` option. Use this to have one player host a game and the other player connect.

See also [the 2k announcement about installing pre-Steamworks Civ IV here.](http://support.2k.com/hc/en-us/articles/202544073-Direct-IP-and-Installing-Pre-Steamworks-Civilization-IV-Unsupported-on-Steam)

It *may* be possible to also get both players running the same version by purchasing the `Civilization: Beyond the Sword` expansion pack for both players, but I haven't confirmed this.